# vsto 2010 outlook addin installed but not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, office-2007

I am developing a VSTO 2010 Office 2007 Outlook Add-In deployed from Click-Once. On the computer I developed it, running Visual Studio, everything works just fine, but when trying to install it on another computer, the addin is installed, and during the startup screen, It comes under **Inactive Applications Add-in**.

In Load Behavior, It shows `Not Loaded.A Runtime error Occured during the loading of the COM-Add-in`.I have changed the Load behavior from 2 to 3 in HKCU under Registry Editor.But it is again reverted back to 2.Not sure how to find the specific error so I can fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this?

Any ideas anyone might have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What **prerequisites** have you checked under your project settings->Publish? Try installing it on your computer first to see if there is an issue on the client machine.

Comment: Try setting [VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003(v=vs.80).aspx) to 0 to help you debug.

Comment: I have installed in my own computer and it works well @SilverNinja. When I'm trying to install it on windows 7 pc,It works fine.But in some windows xp system, the add-in cannot be loaded. Is there any OS compatibility depends on it?

Comment: What is the build platform you are targeting? x86 or x64? Win7 is probably x64 while WinXP is x86. What .NET framework are you using? Win7 probably has the latest .NET 4 while WinXP will only support .NET 2. This is why you want to check the prereqs to ensure you have the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution by myself.What I have done is  Before I published a solution I was checked **.Net Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile** in prerequisites under Install settings and it works for me now.

[image: See Here]